# Shifting bits of 64Bit Ints getting error

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I'm experimenting with bit shifting using UInt64 data type. The code works just as I expected when I use a constant number. However, it fails when I use a variable. The compiler issues "Operator << cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'ulong'" error. How do I go about fixing this code so that I can use a variable in place of a constant number? Here's an excerpt of my code

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       UInt64 x=0;
       int pos = 2;
       x = ((UInt64)x | (1 << pos));
       Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the non working code too?

Comment: That code is non working code.

Comment: The code you've shown produces the error "Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ulong' and 'int'"

Comment: You are mixing signed and unsigned values in an expression.  The C# compiler normally tries to solve this by promoting the values to the next bigger integral type.  But there are none left, UInt64 aka ulong is as big as it can be.  It is therefore up to you to ensure that both operands are the same type.

Answer (score 3):

Try making the right-hand side operand of `|`-operator is of type `UInt64`, e.g.:

```
x = x | (1UL << pos);
```

BTW, one may prefer the compound form:

```
x |= 1UL << pos;
```

Comment: That gives me "Operator << cannot be applied to operands of type ulong and ulong" error.

Comment: @user3273345 Could it be that you made `pos`'s type `UInt64`? It should stay `int`.

Comment: I've deleted my answer but if it helps, heres a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ffiWhq) showing your answer is correct

Comment: @Sayse I just wanted to comment (on the deleted post) that if both operands of `<<` are of type `ulong`, the code does not compile.